# Can we connect Askubuntu with a ubuntu based custom distro?

Tags: discussion, support, scope

We have made some custom distro. We want to connect that custom distro with askubuntu.com . Our distro is the same Ubuntu, with some preinstalled apps and customized so that people can use Linux more easily. So can we connect our custom Ubuntu based distro called *Oikyo Linux* with [askubuntu.com](http://askubuntu.com) ?

Comment: What do you mean "connect"?

Comment: He means getting support on AU

Comment: Getting legal access so that people can ask there problems in askubuntu. @Seth

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to get your name onto this page: http://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/derivatives as a "Recognised Ubuntu flavour" to be able to qualify for support on AskUbuntu (support as in: a special tag named "oikyo" and questions accepted that show that OS's name in the questions)

And that probably only happens if you can prove you can reach more than just a few users and you probably need to fill a hole that the other flavours cover (another chinese version is probably not going to show there. Neither are there going to be othere flavours based on KDE, LXDE or another educational version.

---

There is nothing wrong with asking questions on AU regarding your OS but they should make sure it is related to Ubuntu (so we can help without needing to install your OS).

---

2 examples regarding the 1st comment:

1. you see something challenging in Oikyo, you try the same in a vanilla Ubuntu and see the same happening;
2. you want to change something in Ubuntu to alter it so it is Oikyo specific.

Both are no problem at all (if not asked before of course).

Comment: So can we suggest/redirect users to askubuntu after reviewing their question that it's a system related question of Ubuntu? In case we can't solve it of course.

Comment: see my edit!! :)

Comment: OK, got it. Thanks a lot :)